# AddFontFile XP C#

Tags: c#, fonts

I have a project where I need to load a Postscript font from disk. 
I found I could use "AddFontFile". Doing some research I see that I have to pipe the two fonts http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.text.privatefontcollection.addfontfile.aspx together so I tried:

```
fontCollection = new PrivateFontCollection();
fontCollection.AddFontFile(@"C:\Temp\Font\myfont.PFM|C:\Temp\Font\myfont.PFB");
```

I'm getting a a error "Illegal characters in path".
I'm not sure if I'm piping the two fonts correctly.

Any help would be great, I should mention we are still on XP not sure if that makes a differnts or not.

Mike

Comment: The documentation you link to isn't for the function you're using.

Comment: Anyway, the only thing I can find is [a suggestion on a German forum](http://microsoft.public.de.german.entwickler.dotnet.csharp.narkive.com/kzdNwOod/hinzufugen-von-pfm-und-pfb-fonts) (of all things) to call `AddFontResource` using P/Invoke, and then calling [`Font.FromHfont()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.font.fromhfont.aspx) to wrap it in a `Font` object. (The full code is in the last post at that link.) Unfortunately seemingly untested and without a reply by the OP there.

Comment: I can't find a source, but IIRC you shouldn't repeat the path for the second part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some searching I got it to work and I'd like to share on how I solved the this:
              AddFontFile was the wrong API i Needed to use AddFontResource instead

```
            String fontPath = @"C:\Temp\Font2\GXSTRA03.PFM|C:\Temp\Font2\GXSTRA03.PFB";
            int result = AddFontResource(fontPath);
            long msg = SendMessage(HWND_BROADCAST, WM_FONTCHANGE, IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero);
```

to remove the font resource

```
RemoveFontResource(@"C:\Temp\Font2\GXSTRA03.PFM|C:\Temp\Font2\GXSTRA03.PFB");
long msg = SendMessage(HWND_BROADCAST, WM_FONTCHANGE, IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero);
```

If anyone is new on making a external WinApi call here is the import and import DLL code that I used

```
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

private static uint WM_FONTCHANGE = 0x1D;

        Import("gdi32.dll")]
        static extern int AddFontResource(string lpFilename);

        [DllImport("gdi32.dll")]
        static extern bool RemoveFontResource(string lpFileName);

        [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
        private static extern int SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, uint Msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);
```

This fonts now shows in word and notepad ect..

Answer (score 0):

You cannot have the pipe `|` character in your filename. [PrivateFontCollection.AddFontFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.text.privatefontcollection.addfontfile%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) requires a valid filepath.  Hence your "Illegal characters in path" exception. The input at MSDN is `A String that contains the file name of the font to add.`  Try passing a single file at a time - I don't know about this piping idea..

As for your Postscript desire, the Remarks section states that [OpenTypes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenType) have limited support.

Comment: What I get is a file not found which could indicate that the font is not supported. So I tried it with a TTF font and it worked. so as of now it looks like I have to start looking for a different solutions.

Comment: @Mike That's correct, FileNotFound for an existing file is AddFontFile's exception when it fails.  Microsoft cannot fix this without a breaking change they say. [See here.](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/93610/privatefontcollection-addfontfile-throws-filenotfoundexception-for-existing-files)